# Kth order statistic search

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, unordered

So I've implemented my own kth order statistic search to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array. However I just realized that the algorithm I used (which can be found here: http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/QuickSelect ) returns the element itself, however I would actually like to return the index of the kth largest element. Is there a way to do that instead?

Comment: No it wouldn't because r in this case is the index in the position of the array in the current stack frame, not in the original array

Comment: Read about `std::nth_element`.

Comment: With QuickSelect it is not feasible to return the original index of the k-th statistic. The algorithm is in-place and it scrambles the array. You'd have to make a copy of the original array at the start (or track elements as they move, which also takes O(n) memory and is much more complicated.)

Comment: @RafałDowgird: I think your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

With QuickSelect it is not feasible to return the original index of the k-th statistic. The algorithm is in-place and it scrambles the array. You'd have to make a copy of the original array at the start (or track elements as they move, which also takes O(n) memory and is much more complicated.)